# How to iterate over rows from different dataframe and to use it as a value in other?

Tags: python, pandas, loops, dataframe

I am trying to iterate over the "df_sum" dataframe's 'contract' column by its unique values.
Then create dataframe for each "contract" value for further calculation.

Following is how it goes for a single unique value. I need to iterate over many thousands of unique values.

Here is what the df_sum looks like overall.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/KqNOo.jpg

```
import pandas as pd
from pandas import read_csv


df_sum = read_csv(r'path_to_sum.csv', sep=",", low_memory=False, index_col=False) #summary file

df_EH = df[df['contract']=='EH60906']                 # choose specific contract
df_EH = df_EH.sort_values(by=['datetime'])            # sort specific contract data by datetime and assign as df_EH

... data analysis should follow such as summing up power_pos for each contract number etc.
```

What I tried is as follows:

```
import pandas as pd
from pandas import read_csv
import numpy as np
from datetime import datetime


df_sum = read_csv(r'path_to_sum.csv', sep=",", low_memory=False, index_col=False) #summary file

graph_df = pd.DataFrame()

for contract in df_sum['contract'].unique():
    print(contract)
    contract_df = df[df['contract'] == contract]    
    contract_df.set_index('datetime', inplace=True)
    contract_df.sort_index(inplace = True)
    contract_df."data analysis"

Expected result:
ABABAB.power_pos.sum = 123123
CDCDCD.power_pos.sum = 213124
etc
```

Answer (score 1):

What about this.

```py
df_sum = pd.read_csv(r'path_to_sum.csv', sep=",", low_memory=False, index_col=False)
grouped = df_sum.groupby("contract")["power_pos"].sum()
print(grouped)
```

Comment: Thank you for the comment. For summation, this could work. How about if i were to conduct a linear regression for each "contract" between two columns, for example?